# How to see what is in your Heroku-Postgress DB

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I recently uploaded a WebApplication to Heroku. I developed it using sqlite; however, I then changed it to Heroku-Postgres.
Nonetheless, I am not able to view in any way the data that is in my database.

There are no problems with the code and the WebApplication works perfectly however it would be very useful to be able to tap into the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Heroku CLI and get access to the postgres admin console.

```
heroku pg:psql -a appName
```

Use this command in terminal, This will connect you to pgadmin console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbeaver` database client, but it is very slow because it is free db from heroku.
https://dbeaver.io/download/

Or you can use heroku CLI, psql

Comment: I tried to connect with dbeaver, But its showing FATAL:database "dbname" does not exist. I gave all the details like hostname,password and username very correctly. Could you please help me with this.

Comment: I never got that error, but from `FATAL:database "dbname" does not exist`, you are using `dbname` as database name right? As far as what I remember, heroku free PostgreSQL database give us randomize database name instead of following what we want. For example `d4a570oaere0n`